# How to print path to a txt file in command line?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a folder with two levels of subfolders. (main folder > subfolders level 1 > subfolders level 2 > files) I want to find the folder containing a specific file type. (Subfolders level 2 are organized so that each folder only contains a specific file type, i.e. .txt, .pdf, .png.) and print the path to that subfolder to a txt file.

I've done

```
cd main folder
dir *.pdf* /s > path.txt
```

However, that command prints out:

path to subfolder

1.pdf

2.pdf

3.pdf

path to subfolder

1a.pdf

2a.pdf

3a.pdf

etc.

I just want to print the path to the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

What about `forfiles`?

```
forfiles /S /M *.pdf /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command line returns all sub-directories of the root `main folder` that contain `.pdf` files:

```cmd
for /D /R "main folder" %J in ("*") do @if exist "%~J\*.pdf" echo(%~J
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're dealing with only two levels of directory, there is no reason whatsoever to use a recursive function, which would drill down through all levels.

```sh
(for /d %g in (*)do @for /d %h in ("%g\*")do @if exist "%g\*.pdf" echo %h)>"path.txt"
```

If you want the full path, just change `%h` to `%~fh`

Answer (score 0):

My 1st attempt was to try

`dir /S "*.pdf" |find "\" >path.txt`

but that gives

```
 Directory of C:\level1
 Directory of C:\level1\Folder2
 Direct....
```

and I guess you don't want those "Directory of "

My second attempt is thus

`For /R %F in (.) do @if exist "%F\*.pdf" echo %~fF >>path-pdfs.txt`

**NOTE:- in a .cmd file** the % needs to be doubled

```
@echo off
cd "main folder"
REM First clear any old entries
echo( >path-pdfs.txt
For /R %%F in (.) do @if exist "%%F\*.pdf" echo %%~fF >>path-pdfs.txt
```

which should return

```
C:\level1
C:\level1\Folder3
C:\Lev...etc.
```